# Draw a horizontal bar chart from right to left

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

I am creating a horizontal bar chart in Chart.js as you can see [in this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mosamadi/tc0x4ghb/10/).

I want to change the chart direction so that it draws from right to left. I tried `dir = rtl` and in CSS `direction=rtl` but they don't work.

This is what I want:
[image: expected chart output]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can't find a native way in the documentation to do this, but you can do it via the fairly simple workaround of negating the data so that Chart.js draws negative values:

1. invert the values in the dataset:

   ```
   data.datasets[0].data.map((currentValue, index, array) => {
     array[index] = currentValue * -1;
   });
   ```
2. right-align the y-axis:

   ```
   scales: {
     yAxes: [{
       position: 'right'
       ...
   ```
3. reformat tooltips for display:

   ```
   options = {
     tooltips: {
     callbacks: {
       label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
         var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';

         if (label) {
           label += ': ';
         }
         label += tooltipItem.xLabel * -1;
         return label;
       }
     }
     ...
   ```
4. reformat ticks for display:

   ```
   xAxes: [{
     ticks: {
       callback: function(value, index, values) {
         return value * -1;
       }
   ...
   ```

Here's a working example:

```js
var data = {
  labels: ["x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "Actual",
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)',
    borderWidth: 1,
    data: [40, 150, 50, 60, 70],
    yAxisID: "bar-y-axis1"
  }]
};

// invert the sign of each of the values.
data.datasets[0].data.map((currentValue, index, array) => {
  array[index] = currentValue * -1;
});

var options = {
  tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
      label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
        var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';

        if (label) {
          label += ': ';
        }
        label += tooltipItem.xLabel * -1; // invert the sign for display.
        return label;
      }
    }
  },
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      id: "bar-y-axis1",
      categoryPercentage: 0.5,
      barPercentage: 0.5,
      position: 'right' // right-align axis.
    }],

    xAxes: [{
      id: "bar-x-axis1",
      stacked: false,
      ticks: {
        callback: function(value, index, values) {
          return value * -1; // invert the sign for tick labelling.
        },
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }]
  }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with this in [Chart.js v4](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/api/interfaces/CoreScaleOptions.html). Its same keyword in lower version:

```
var options = {
  scales: {
    x: { reverse: true },
  },
}
```

Docs: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/api/interfaces/CoreScaleOptions.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This question is asked more than 2 years ago and it has an accepted answer. Please add some details about the reason you are adding a new answer